# How many users used the facebook app?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-apps

I need to know how many users used my app. Now what is the correct definition of how many users used my app ?. What's the difference between active users, installed users and users who have used the app.

[image]

For example look at this graph i have attached. There are three numbers i am looking New installs (6554), Lifetime installed users(5431) and monthly active users(Highest at 17k+). What's the difference ? And what should be the answer when my question is how many users used my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation of the different figures:

`New installs` - How many users have installed your app in a certain time period.
`Lifetime Installed Users` - How many users have ever installed your app (up to a certain point in time which is indicated when you hover on the ? beside the label).
`Monthly/Daily/Weekly Active Users` - How many users have actively used your app in a certain time period

It's your choice which of those figures you want to use to say how many 'use' your app, but DAU/WAU/MAU are probably the most honest in terms of real, actual users.

Comment: So if it's 17k users at max on a day at MAU. Can i say that these many people used my app ?

Comment: Well, it's only true if you describe the time period involved (October through December), given that your MAU has dropped back off again. Looking at the graph you have posted, it looks like you currently have close to 0 users though.